# Remote API server slowiness

Tags: performance, twitter, webserver

In our server we reach api.twitter.com and use REST API of Twitter. Until 3 days ago we had no problems. But since that time we have slowiness problem.

Regarding to [Twitter API status page](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/status) there is no problem. But we have very big delays.
We make 350-400 requests per minute.
Before, we had a performance of 600-700 ms. per request. ([Snapshot image](http://s6.postimg.org/s53h8d44x/aaaa.jpg))
But now it became 3600-4000 ms per request. ([Snapshot image](http://s6.postimg.org/76xbaa4a9/bbbb.jpg))

It doesn't look like a temporary slowiness because it remains nearly for 3 days.
What did I check:
- I didn't make any big code change in our repo. Also when we make minimal reuqests with just one line of request, we still get this slowiness.
- I check server speed with Ookla's speedtest. It looks good. 800 Mb/s download, 250 Mb/s upload.
- We don't have any CPU, RAM or disk problem. CPU average is 30%, RAM is 50% loaded, disk IO is nearly 4-5%.

So what would be the probable causes ?
I can check them and update question.

(Centos 6.5, PHP 5.4.36, Nginx 1.6, Apache/2.2.15, Apache run PHP as PHP module, XCache 3.2.0)

Comment: This really is something you'll need to address with Twitter.  I assume you've already done a traceroute to see with path the data is taking?

Comment: I asked Twitter but I didn't get any actual response from them. Pinging twitter.com gives 125 ms average, also traceroute response similar.